# How do I use ES6 code instead of a for loop here?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, ecmascript-6

I am looking for better way to handle the search of array. This is what I have right now.

```
function search (arr, word) {
  word = word.toUpperCase();
  var res = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i].slice(0, word.length) == word) {
      res.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return res;
}

var myArr = ["england", "China", "France", "Eng", "Ch", "Australia"];

search(myArr, "e");
```

It works, but I would like to replace for loop with ES6 code as I am trying to learn it. How could I utilize ES6 here?

Comment: `es6` is a spec, not a function/method call. What do you mean by replace it with `es6`?

Comment: Unrelated but it looks like there's a bug as you convert the word to uppercase, but not the words in the array. So for example, it won't return "england" for the letter "e".

Comment: @Polina Your current code is only returning `Eng` not `england`

Comment: What is 'better'? While not being good-looking solution, `for` is likely the most performant solution.

Comment: @Weedoze Hmm... It works for me thought here is my repo -  https://repl.it/JDvw

Comment: @Estus by better I meant more modern, short and fast.  I agree that for loop is really performant solution, the reason why I am asking other options is  learning purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could utilize a few builtin methods such as [`String#startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) and [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
function search(arr, word) {
  return arr.filter(element => element.toUpperCase().startsWith(word.toUpperCase()));
}

const myArr = ["england", "China", "France", "Eng", "Ch", "Australia"];
console.log(search(myArr, "e"));
```

The `filter` method only keeps elements in the array that meet the certain condition specified by the callback. Thus it checks if the element starts with the word regardless of case.

And if you need support for IE, try using [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
element.toUpperCase().indexOf(word.toUpperCase()) == 0
```

This will check if the element starts with the specified string, regardless of case and is functionally equivalent.

---

Note that although it doesn't look pretty, the `for` loop is a better in terms of performance as [estus noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44782001/replace-for-loop-with-es6#comment76544986_44782001). After testing it looks like it takes the `for` loop around 0.1 milliseconds to complete and my solution ranges from 0.2 to 0.7 milliseconds to complete. Though there's a difference, I wouldn't worry about performance until it really matters -- but the faster one here is your solution.

Comment: Thank you, this is just something I  wanted! Much shorter and nicer than my code, thanks a lot!

Comment: thank you for explanation and comment about for loop!